# h:commandLink actionlistener is not invoked when used with f:ajax and ui:repeat

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, commandlink

h:commandLink actionlistener is not invoked when used with f:ajax and ui:repeat
When I click the link, I have to pass a parameter in the bean's "onload" method and refresh the panelgroup "assist". It works fine when I use the commandButton but not with commandLink.

```
<h:panelGroup id="assist" styleClass="tabbed-panel-vertical">
<ul id="assistlink" class="tabbed-panel-vertical-tabs">
    <ui:repeat var="assistants"
        value="#{permissions.repAssistants}">
        <li><h:commandLink 
                            actionListener="#{permissions.onload}"
            value="#{assistants.name}"
                styleClass="#{permissions.selectedAssistant==assistants.userId ? 'selected' : ''}">
                <f:ajax
                    render=":permissionsform:assist :permissionsform:permissionsContent"
                    execute="@this">
                    <f:attribute name="assistantId"
                        value="#{assistants.userId}" />
                </f:ajax>
            </h:commandLink></li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

```
    `public void onload(ActionEvent event) {
    Long userId = Long.valueOf(541);// user.getUserId();
    Long assistantId = (Long) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("assistantId");
    System.out.println("User " + assistantId); 
    }`
```

Comment: Please describe in detail how exactly it fails. Please mention exact JSF impl/version.

Comment: Jsf 2.0, mojarra impl. The method "onload" is never invoked when I click on the commandlink. When I replace the commandLink with a commandButton, I see that the method gets invoked.
output generated from commandLink: 
<a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('permissionsform'),{'j_idt13:0:j_idt15':'j_idt13:0:j_idt15'},'');return false" class="">PATRICK CARROLL</a>
output generated with command link: <input type="submit" name="j_idt13:0:j_idt15" value="PATRICK CARROLL" class="selected" />

Comment: "JSF 2.0" is a specification. Which Mojarra version are you using? Which browsers have you used? Are there any errors in JavaScript console when you click the link? How does the ajax request/response look like? By the way, the `<f:attribute>` approach doesn't work as you'd expect it would work, but this is a different problem.

Comment: By the way, this piece of code works perfectly fine for me with Mojarra 2.1.7 on the most recent versions of all the four major webbrowsers (expect of course that the `<f:attribute>` doesn't work the way as you intended). So your problem is caused by something else which is not shown in the code so far.

Comment: @BalusC Its javascript issue. Thanks for directing me to look at the javascript console.
JS error "Uncaught ReferenceError: mojarra is not defined"

Comment: I will try with mojarra 2.1.7 and try to dig deeper into the javascript. Thanks for now.

Comment: The JavaScript error helped much in understanding the cause and thus the solution simply became obvious. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments:

> *@BalusC Its javascript issue. Thanks for directing me to look at the javascript console. JS error "Uncaught ReferenceError: mojarra is not defined"*

Make sure that you've a `<h:head>` tag in your master template instead of `<head>`. This way JSF will be able to auto-include the necessary JavaScript file for the Ajax magic.