# mojarra is not defined when javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE is Production

Tags: jsf

Today I got the exception "mojarra is not defined".

I stumbled in the following questions: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248047/mojarra-is-not-defined-commandlink-not-making-a-request), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009238/mojarra-is-not-defined) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933777/hcommandlink-actionlistener-is-not-invoked-when-used-with-fajax-and-uirepeat).

Neither of those solver my issue.

After some debugging I fixed the issue by changing javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE param in web.xml from:

```
<param-value>Production</param-value>
```

to:

```
<param-value>Development</param-value>
```

It fixed the issue, but what should I do when putting my project in production? Should I leave the param on development?

Comment: I've never seen this problem. Please nail down the root cause. The JavaScript object with variable name `mojarra` is defined in `jsf.js` file which is supposed to be auto-included if you have a `<h:head>`. Look in the generated HTML output. Is the `jsf.js` file present in the head? Look in the browser's builtin HTTP traffic monitor. Did it return the proper response to the browser or a 404 or so? The only difference with project stages is that the development stage appends a query string to the URL which causes a non-minified version to be returned.

Comment: It's also quite possible that you were testing both MyFaces and Mojarra and that the browser is agressively caching the MyFaces version of the `jsf.js` file. But a rather straightforward clear of browser cache and/or hard refresh should fix it.

Comment: My component calls `mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'menu-form:pagina-select')` in development mode the `jsf.js` is mojarra, but when in production mode it seems to be a minified version of my faces, small extract of the beginning of the `jsf.js` in production mode: `if(!window.myfaces){var myfaces=new function(){};window.myfaces=myfaces;}`, even though my component still call `mojarra.ab(...)`. I'll double check my server configuration.

Comment: Clear browser cache. If a proxy is used, contact its admin as well to clear its cache.

Answer (score 0):

> *My component calls mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'menu-form:pagina-select') in development mode the jsf.js is mojarra, but when in production mode it seems to be a minified version of my faces, small extract of the beginning of the jsf.js in production mode: if(!window.myfaces){var myfaces=new function(){};window.myfaces=myfaces;}, even though my component still call mojarra.ab(...). I'll double check my server configuration*

You've apparently experimented with both Mojarra and MyFaces and the MyFaces version of `jsf.js` is hanging in an agressive cache somewhere in the network pipeline. Clear at least the browser's and, if any, also the proxy's cache.

That it works in development stage is because the URL of the `jsf.js` contains an additional query string unique to Mojarra (it would return a non-minified version to ease debugging).

Comment: I'm running this in localhost. I cleared my cache and started the application with Production set and got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into same trouble these days and i figured out, that it was caused by my extendend omnifaces resourcehandler.

```
public class VersionableResourceHandler extends DefaultResourceHandler {
  //...
  @Override
  public Resource decorateResource(Resource resource) {
    if (resource == null) {
        return resource;
    }
    return new RemappedResource(resource, resource.getRequestPath() + "?v=1_2_1");
  }
}
```

with

```
<param-value>Development</param-value>
```

the generated output with my appended version-string will be:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development%3Fv=1_2_1"/>
```

with

```
<param-value>Production</param-value>
```

generated output looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces%3Fv=1_2_1"/>
```

which is invalid because of the second "?", so "?v=1_2_1" had to be replaced by "&v=1_2_1".